# IdentityServer - client not aware user claims have been updated

Tags: identityserver3

I've a MVC site that requires two factor auth for a number of actions. Not all users require 2fa so this isn't set upon login.

I've an AuthorizationAttribute that checks the users claims for a specific 2fa claims.

```
 protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {

      var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)httpContext.User;
      if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          return false;
      }

      return
          principal.Claims.Any(
              x =>
                  x.Type == MyClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod &&
                  x.Value == AuthenticationMethods.TwoFactorAuthentication);

  }
```

If they are not present I send them off to my 2fa controller in the Identity server which prompts the user for 2fa codes etc. This then updates the users claims with those I check for in the attribute and send them back to my site.

On the IdentityServer I have the following

```
var claims = user.Claims.Where(c => c.Type != "amr").ToList();
                claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, Constants.AuthenticationMethods.TwoFactorAuthentication));
                claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.AuthenticationMethods.TwoFactorAuthentication, twoFactorProvider));

                if (fullLogin)
                {

                    user.RemoveClaim(user.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "amr"));
                    user.AddClaims(claims);
                    var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(user.Claims);

                    context.Authentication.SignIn(newIdentity);     

                }
```

However my site is none the wiser of the users new claims.

How can i make the check above in my attribute find the newly acquired claims??

Comment: When this re-auth is triggered, does it include a "acr_values" param to tell the token server that 2fa is required?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated the question with the code from my 2fa controller. I do not use any "acr_values".